# How do I disable Nav_header_main?

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

Can someone explain how I can disable the `Nav_Header_Main` in Android Studio?

Tried to delete it from the design tab but then I keep receiving errors when trying to run my code.

The green bit beneath:

[image]

Comment: can you post your code and what you tried in detail

Comment: I haven't really tried anything - the main code is within the nav_header_main.xml file

Answer (score 0):

open your xml file where you define DrawerLayout and remove header layout from navigation view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_content"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

        //remove headerlayout line. that is it.
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"

        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```